# What are the penalties for being late for work?

Tags: the-sims-4

I'm trying to burn through career promotions for aspirations quicky. Part of this is getting the sim in a proper mood before leaving for work. I queue up finishing of the daily task and studying some object to make my sim focused before they leave for work.

By doing so, it often happens that my sim doesnt actually leave the house until 1 hour after they had to go to work. On one occasion it was even 2 hours.

Are there any penalties for getting late to work, like...

- The job performance meter only moves when you work? (and by being late it has less time in a day)
- Sims get paid by hour, not day?
- Fixed penalties like treating it as not coming in for work once a few hours pass?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't go to work, after ~90 minutes you'll get a call from the boss letting you know that you're missing work.  It is ok to not answer the call, or answer the call and still not go.

Sims are paid hourly.  The more hours you miss, the less pay you get.  I tested this with two sims at level 1 business career.  One sim earned $128 ($16 * 8), while the other earned $98 ($16 * ~6).

Work performance does suffer while you are not at work.  Work performance also does not accrue while you're not at work.

From a gameplay standpoint, it's probably worth being an hour late if you can enter a favorable mood.  Of course, if you could get the mood without being late that would be better.

Comment: Thanks for testing, it seems pay per hour is a very natural penalty to getting late to work. Much less abusable than the earlier sim games.

Comment: If you're supposed to start work at 9am, what time do you need to leave the house to earn full pay?

Comment: @BraddSzonye I'll try to find out.  If it helps, the sim which earned for 6.125 hours only worked 5 hours.

Comment: Thanks! I suspect that the game is set up so that you earn full pay so long as you leave home reasonably close to your start time, but I’m curious to find out just how it works. I haven’t had time to experiment myself yet.

Answer (score 0):

So far, there is no penalty for beign late for work at any Sims game.

The penalty comes if you don't go to work.